# Angularjs: How to pass specific data to modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm struggling to display 'nested' [array] data in my modal. I am able to see all my data fetched from a url in angular, on my view page. However, when I ng-click on the same element to pop out a modal to see the same information on the modal, I can't see some of the information. In this case I cant the employees or developers.

**url fetching code in angular**

```
**controller used is 'HomeController'
**/comments is where my json data is located with 'employees' 
being a one-to-many relationship entity in my backend (which might be the issue in my head)

var vm = this;
vm.projects = [];
$http.get('/comments')
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        vm.projects = result.data; 
     });
```

**`data`** as used in my modal template (not working code in modal)

```
    <div ng-repeat="data in controller.projects">
        <ul ng-repeat="employee in data.employees">
            {{employee.name}}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

`controller` comes from `<div ng-controller="HomeController as controller">`

I have also tried this;

```
    <div ng-repeat="employee in Project.Employees" class="selected-item">
        {{employee.name}}
    </div>
```

but doesn't work!

As seen below, the `employees` show up on the 'normal' page.

[image]

However, when I `ng-click="editProject(data)"` the above card to pop up the modal, everything else shown above (not shown below here) pops up except the employees. Could it be a routing issue?

[image]

Basically everything works perfect on the template view until I pop out the modal. This is the "modal popping" code;

```
$scope.editProject = function(data) {
    $scope.showSelected = true;
    $scope.SelectedProject = data;
    var fromDate = moment(data.start).format('DD/MM/YYYY LT');
    var endDate  = moment(data.end).format('DD/MM/YYYY LT');

    $scope.Project = { 
        ProjectID : data.projectID, 
        Client : data.client,
        Title : data.title,
        Description: data.description,
        Employees: data.employees,
        StartAt : fromDate,
        EndAt : endDate,
        IsFullDay : false
    }

     $scope.ShowModal()
},

//This function is for show modal dialog
$scope.ShowModal = function(){
    $scope.option = {
        templateUrl: 'modalContent.html',
        controller: 'modalController',
        backdrop: 'static',
        resolve: {
            Project : function () { 
                return $scope.Project;
            },
            SelectedProject : $scope.SelectedProject                  
        }
    };
```

Could there be a promise I'm missing in the `ShowModal` `resolve`?

Meanwhile in chrome devtools, the `employees` seemed to have been 'picked' up as shown below;

[image]

However when I open the object, interestingly it says array is empty;

[image]

I am new to angular and web development in general. Let me know if you need me to reveal my backend or any other code you think is missing. I'm just thinking it's an angular issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It does not say that array is empty. can you expand the Employees  node?

Comment: are you using angularUI bootstrap? https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ for your modal? or something else?

Comment: @Deep expanded as updated above.

Comment: @haxxxton yes I am using angular UIbootstrap.

Comment: you want complete details of the employee in the modal?

Comment: @Aravind yes but for now I just want to something as simple as `employee.name` to display then I can take it from there.

Comment: @colin_dev256  ShowModal function is just opening the modal only for this functionality or it is re used.

Comment: @Aravind it is opened to display all the project's details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass *projects* as dependency injection to you modal instance controller:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl',   function ($uibModalInstance, projects) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.projects = projects;

  $ctrl.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close();
  };

  $ctrl.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
  };
});
```

and resolve it in your opening function:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($http, $uibModal, $log, $document) {
  var $ctrl = this;

  $http.get('data.json').then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    $ctrl.projects = result.data; 
  });

  $ctrl.open = function (size, parentSelector) {
    var parentElem = parentSelector ? 
      angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-demo ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      size: size,
      appendTo: parentElem,
      resolve: {
        projects: function () {
          return $ctrl.projects;
        }
      }
    });
  };
});
```

please note also that controller name is passed with `controllerAs` property and not within HTML template.

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/wLI0pa07UNhr9Ld8CSg3?p=preview

Comment: I actually half done in this but  you delivered.. :)

Comment: @Aravind one more thing. What if I just want to simply display only one of the `employees` in `data.json`?

Comment: if you used this solution in your app. I will be able to fix that for you. Can you share your version of the solution.\

Comment: it's fine, you can use your plunker. I'll get the logic.

Comment: @Aravind yours wasnt much different from mine. i just had to add `ctrl` in both scopes plus `projects` to the `resolve` and `controller`.